# Rails: Assign users a random default avatar (ala Twitter)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, avatar

I'm using [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle avatar's for users and currently set a default image using:

`:default_url => '/images/img-missing_:style.png'`

But what I'd like to do is when a user registers, give them a random avatar that they get until they upload their own.

Twitter does this with its "egg" avatar and that have probably half a dozen different colors that get assigned.

How can I accomplish this?

Note, I'm not wanting to show a random avatar every time a call to the user is made, rather I want them to be assigned a random avatar when they register and have that one stick with them until they upload their own.

Comment: may be maintain a counter on the server session and loop through it, lets say you have 10 Avatars to choose from Randomly.. maintain a Server Session Variable that resets everytime when the limit is reached.. PHP maintains these Server Side Session Variables, not sure how Ruby on Rails would deal with it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have 10 default avatars, you could use the modulus of their user ID to determine which one is displayed. This would be consistent and trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the User Name length as a way to determine what picture is used as default avatar, let's say i sign up with username: villain (which is 7 characters)

you can use 7 as a means to reference image number 7 (say, 7.png) to set as the default avatar.

To make it look more consistent, add in clauses like:

```
 0) First, check that the username falls within a plausible character length.. (say 6-14)
 1) if number is even, divide by 2 and use the result to pick up the image.
 2) if result is odd, use the number as it is to pick up the default avatar.
```

So, in my case above, you can use 7 as the magic number and may be avatar 7.png as default for this user..

Comment: I can't imagine you'd an even distribution doing it that way.

Comment: Oh, offcourse this wont be an even distribution... middle numbers would be used more than the ones on the far low side and high side..